# Reset LineChart y axis

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex

I have a LineChart, which is try and 'reset' by setting the dataprovider as null. Now if in the first instance of the chart I have negative value, the y axis 'expands' so as to show negative values, which is awesome. Once I reset, I get a graph with no data points, but the y axis still remains on the old 'expanded' state. I was wondering if there is anyway I can get the y axis to return to the default state as well?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try:

```
yourLineChart.validateNow();
```